# Looking for a good example of cleanly doing PHP database sessions

Tags: php, database, session

Trying to use database sessions in PHP without re-inventing the wheel so I'm looking for a clean library or example that could send me in the right direction.

Comment: You will probably have to use a framework to have a good library. Try Zend Framework or CakePHP.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid adding in a framework like Zend or CakePHP. We're building this lightweight with only a router and PDO. So we really want to avoid anything beyond a light library or code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Zend Framework** provides a solution on database sessions: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.savehandler.dbtable.html

Comment: Don't I have to accept the Zend Framework wholesale in order to use this?

Comment: I believe you can just use parts from zend framework.